# Swagger UI: Add api section manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swagger-ui

I have configured swagger ui in my asp.net web api application. The swagger ui lists all the APIs exposed via api controllers.

I am using `OWIN` and have an oauth access token endpoint configured via `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions`. I want to add this to the swagger UI as well.
I figured it might not be possible for swagger to self discover this endpoint. Hence, I am looking for a way to somehow manually inject the token endpoint meta into swagger.
Please let me know how this can be done.

Comment: I suppose what you need is described right in documentation, section "Describing Security/Authorization Schemes": https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle